# How to pass information from one activity to another in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a Journey with two activities in it. One "Create Lead" Activity and after that an email activity. If I go to Journey Settings, I can see in Journey Data that Create Lead Activity has a parameter "SalesforceObjectID" that I would like to pass to the next email Activity.

Is this possible anyhow? Would be possible with a custom activity instead? as I saw something in this thread:
[Pass Personalization Data in Custom Activity](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219833/pass-personalization-data-in-custom-activity/220080) but it is not clear for me.

The idea would be via AMPScript to show that data into the email sent by the email activity.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your email that follows the Lead activity that creates a record, use the [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) Ampscript function to find the lead based on your Journey Data - this way you'll be able to grab `SalesforceObjectID` that you need. Maybe introduce a small wait activity between the Lead activity and the email.

Comment: Hi Rafal! Thanks a million for the suggestion!! I gave just an example but if I have a JB Custom Activity that I'm sending data outArgument and I want to retrieve it, would be the same?

Comment: @Mrquestion I have no experience in developing custom activities, but I found an article here that says you can only pass data between 2 custom activities, but not from a custom one to a standard one (like email sends): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145410/update-contact-with-custom-activity-outargument